# how does web view Load Html Content?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am getting this html content in Response via the variable: `String mresult=`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
</head>
<body style="width:300px; color: #00000; ">

<p><strong> About us</strong> </p>
<p><strong> Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text .</p>

<p><strong> Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text </p>

<p><strong> Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text </p>

</body></html>
```

It could not load in `webview`, I have to try to load it like this:

```
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, mresult, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

still `webview` displays a Blank white page.

In the `xml` file:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/wV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"          
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
```

In the Activity:

```
String mresult="Here my given data";
WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wV);
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
web.loadData(mresult, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Your code works in my emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't know y still it not loading in `webview` but given result is display in `TextView` in `Html` format like

```
TextView  txtweb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtweb);
txtweb.setText(Html.fromHtml(mresult));
```

Answer (score 24):

Use this Html_value in this way:

```
String html_value = "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"><title>Lorem Ipsum</title></head><body style=\"width:300px; color: #00000; \"><p><strong> About us</strong> </p><p><strong> Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text .</p><p><strong> Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text </p><p><strong> Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text </p></body></html>";
```

this is used into webview then only it will work because your html tag was not properly closed:

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.sample);
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.loadData(html_value, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

output:

[image]

Comment: mresult.replaceAll("\"","\"");

Comment: You could use ' instead of " in the string, String mresult = "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'><title>Lorem Ipsum</title></head><body style='width:300px; color: #00000; '><p><strong> About us</strong> </p><p><strong> Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text .</p><p><strong> Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text </p><p><strong> Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text </p></body></html>";

Comment: this string m getting from webservice with some more details

Comment: try displaying the string in a TextView or maybe use Log.d() to see if it is properly formatted.

Comment: i have check in  log and String mm= "\"";
    String rm= "\\\"";
       String temp = mresult.replaceAll(mm,rm);

Comment: but could not String also replace

Comment: content same as wich given no change

Comment: No need to replace \ the purpose of \ the html value is not end. if you not mention \ your next value not taken that's why, we are applying this \ otherwise your next value not assign in webview eg : error :"<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">"; I am not apply the \ value in this html tag so we get only "<html xmlns=" value next value we will not get right if you need to next value you should apply the \ then only you will get this value http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml reason "" ends with your tag. if you apply\ then only it will be read next tag.

Comment: Still you are facing same problem tell me i will give another solution ....@ankitmakwana

Answer (score 4):

```
    wb.loadDataWithBaseURL("", result, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for the WebView:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
wv.loadData(mresult, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: here only display Blank white Browser

Comment: check for the width/height of the webView in your XML, or if it is via code, you should add layout parameters. maybe paste the whole code to see if there are any other possible problems.

Comment: check now given xml And Activity details

Comment: Strange, your code works, do you have your project somewhere online like github, or maybe paste the whole XML, and with the WebView definition, and the whole activity.

Comment: `; charset=UTF-8` was the key for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
  webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlParsing, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
  webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

in htmlparsing: just pass urs html code.

It works....