# How to display html list in RecyclerView ？

Tags: android, html, android-recyclerview

Display complex styled html as list in `recyclerview`. It is a stupid requirement, I have tried `RichText`， but `RichText` does not support `css`.

Comment: did you try **`Webview`**

Comment: Only option available is web view i guess .If there will be a single web view then its ok go for it. In other case Webview as a list item is not the recommended way . Web view is itself a browser putting it as list item will consume memory, Your list will lag on scroll.You need to find some other way around  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Display complex styled html as list in recyclerview.

You can use **`Webview`** to Load Html

> **[WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)**
>   A View that displays web pages. This class is the basis upon which you can roll your own web browser or simply display some online content within your Activity. It uses the WebKit rendering engine to display web pages and includes methods to navigate forward and backward through a history, zoom in and out, perform text searches and more.

Load your `HTML` data in `WebView` using [`WebView.loadData()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) method

- `loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding)`

  > Loads the given data into this WebView using a 'data' scheme URL.
- `loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)`

  > Loads the given data into this WebView, using baseUrl as the base URL for the content.

**Sample Code**

```
String htmlString = "<h1>PREM 1.</h1>\n" +
                    "<h2>PREM 2.</h2>\n" +
                    "<h3>PREM 3.</h3>";
WebView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so detailed, I know how to use WebView，but never in a ListView or RecyclerView,  I thought it is a bad performance, I would like to know if there is any way to make optimization. By the way, if it is possible to load css string dynamically to WebView.

Comment: @yuiopt yes you can load css string dynamically to WebView.

Comment: @yuiopt also check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15808070/7666442